# The red globs in terraria

Tags: terraria

I have hit one of those globs that looks like a supper mutant gore bag over and over again with a hammer. Does anything happen if I keep hitting it?

Comment: The linked one is different.

Comment: It looks like they're talking about crimson hearts, not crimson altars...